# unable to get data from sql using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Am using `PDO` method to get data from SQL But am unable to get data from `SQL` database since am new to `PDO` its little hard to understand

but i did the following code but Doesn't work can someone help me

### CODE

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "sanoj";
$password = "123456";
$dbname = "test";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM members");
    $stmt->execute();
    // set the resulting array to associative
    $membid=($_GET['memberID']);
$email=($_GET['email']);
$state=($_GET['username']);
    }
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}



echo $membid;
echo $email;
echo $state;
$conn = null;
echo "</table>";
?>
```

### ERROR I GET

```
Notice: Undefined index: memberID in C:\Users\sanoj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\godaddy optimized\data.php on line 14
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0020  132392  {main}( )   ..\data.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\Users\sanoj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\godaddy optimized\data.php on line 15
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0020  132392  {main}( )   ..\data.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\Users\sanoj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\godaddy optimized\data.php on line 16
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0020  132392  {main}( )   ..\data.php:0
```

Comment: `unable`, `doesn't work`... What error do you get?

Comment: i get `Undefined index:` on line 14, 15, 16

Comment: Let us see your `URL` from where you call this script. Add the `<form>` code or the Ajax call if any.

Comment: @D4V1D i don't use script or `URL` am learning how to get data from sql in `PDO` am am stuck with this

Comment: You don't use `URL`?? Of course you do. Where do you think you get your `$membid`, `$email`, `$state` from?

Comment: @D4V1D i have added error to Question

Comment: **How** do you access to this page?

Comment: @D4V1D i simple run this page in `net beans` using `wamp server`

Comment: Don't you need to use a web browser like Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: using chrome browser

Comment: So what's the URL in the adress bar?

Comment: @D4V1D this the `URL` `http://localhost:8000/data.php`

Comment: So, again, **where** do you think you get your `$membid`, `$email`, `$state`?

Comment: @D4V1D FRom SQL using php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `$_GET` variable won't make you *get* your data from your database using PDO. You were doing right up until `$stmt->execute();`. What you need to do next is:

```
while($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{ 
    foreach($result as $key => $value)
        echo $key.': '.$value.'<br/>';
    echo '<hr/>';
}
```

To get your data.

[`$_GET` array](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) is to fetch your data from the `URL` or from a `GET` Ajax call.

Comment: but it display only one row what about rest

Comment: what should i do to get all rows

Comment: if there are many rows i need to select one row in random `SELECT * FROM select ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` will this work

Comment: if i want to `echo` how can i do ?? like this `echo $membid;
echo $email;
echo $state;` because result are in array i don't want to use array

Comment: Retrieve them as so `$variable = $result['fieldname'];` where `fieldname` are `memberID`, `email` and `username`.